# Issue with Php-redis - socket.io to emit to specific user

Tags: socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis

I got an issue with php-redis with socket.io ,in their example here 
https://github.com/rase-/socket.io-php-emitter
im trying to emit to specific user which is set on my socket.io nodejs server , in a varible called:
var users = {}; this carible contain the socket id , when user connect to the node server im saving its socket . on its user_id 
users[data.id] = socket;

anyone can help me understand how do i send to a specific user my way or another way usingphp redis

Answer (score 0):

Ok so eventually i did not use the php emitter , i was installing the php redis and use the publish function to communicate between the php <-redis-> nodejs. 
i publish with diffrent keywords to recognize what action i want to preform in the nodejs and depanding on that i was emitting the right action to the right user/s.

hope my answer helped